# How to make jtable on full jframe window

Tags: java, swing, layout, jtable, jframe

i am trying to create a jtable using java swing  and little bit i am able to do this but problem is this that i want to create that jtable on full jframe window how can i do this  here is my code given below

```
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.table.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class ScrollableJTable{
  public static void main(String[] args) {
  new ScrollableJTable();
  }
  public ScrollableJTable(){
  JFrame frame = new JFrame("Creating a Scrollable JTable!");
  JPanel panel = new JPanel();
  String data[][] = {{"001"},
};
  String col[] = {"Roll"};
  JTable table = new JTable(data,col);
  JTableHeader header = table.getTableHeader();
  header.setBackground(Color.yellow);
    Toolkit tk = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit(); 
  int xSize = ((int) tk.getScreenSize().getWidth());  
  int ySize = ((int) tk.getScreenSize().getHeight()); 
  JScrollPane pane = new JScrollPane(table);
  table.setAutoResizeMode(JTable.AUTO_RESIZE_OFF);
  panel.add(pane);
  frame.add(panel);
 frame.setSize(xSize,ySize);  

  frame.setUndecorated(true);
  frame.getRootPane().setWindowDecorationStyle(JRootPane.PLAIN_DIALOG);
  frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
  frame.setVisible(true);
  }
}
```

How can i achieve my desired output?

hanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple, set the layout manager for `panel` as `BorderLayout` or simple add the `JScrollPane` (`pane`) directly to the frame, which uses a `BorderLayout` by default

Take a look at [Laying Out Components Within a Container](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html) for more details

Comment: can you please tell me  how?

Comment: See the link.  It's the same for any component, `setLayout(new BorderLayout())`

Comment: i did not get mean by JscrollPane(pane) directly to the frame

Comment: Instead of adding `pane` to `panel`, just add `pane` to the frame

Answer (score 0):

cool..you do not need to write so many lines of code to display a file.Just download the jar file rs2xml and add it to your project library.

**Note**: This will be useful if you are using netbeans

How to use it?

- create the table in backend
- download rs2xml jar file
- Add it to the project library
- drag the jtable from the swing controls to your jframe

Now write the following code as follows:

write ur query:

```
        ps=con.prepareStatement("select * from register");       
        ResultSet r=ps.executeQuery();
        jTable1.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(r)); //display the register table
```

Comment: This is no way related to this question _at all_. Looks more like spam to _me_

Comment: you can drag your jtable to fit in to the jframe.Its easy.I think you are not using swing controls in netbeans.That is why my previous suggestion looks spam to you.Just try it.